# How to open and read a .bug file from Blackberry?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I got an error,
I used the option "catfail" (navigate to it using the arrow keys when you get an error) and saved a log of the error.

But now I can't read the bug file. it's all encrypted I think.

here is a little part of it:

> ÿ õÄM³Ô ÿ ¶Ô(   (   Z Àabsadmin  Nov 21 2008 19:38     yÃg   {Ãgfledge.exe   {Ãg/app=Jvm.dll   {Ãg/h

the file itself is called 8900.bug (8900: the device simulator)

And i notice a lot more characters in the file that stackoverflow isn't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following: in notepad, press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**, and search for 'VECM'. This will show you the method where the error occurs.

There is much more info in the .bug file, but it's a start.